# Scaled gradient descent

Tags: reference-request, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Consider the unconstrained minimization
\begin{align*}
\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)
\end{align*}
One iterative approach to obtaining a solution is to use the gradient descent algorithm. This algorithm generates iterates via the following rule (assuming that $f$ is differentiable)
\begin{align*}
x_{k+1} = x_k - \alpha_k\nabla f(x_k)
\end{align*}
Now consider a different algorithm, termed the *scaled gradient descent* algorithm. This algorithm takes the form
\begin{align*}
x_{k+1} = x_k - \alpha_kD_k^{-1}\nabla f(x_k)
\end{align*}
where $D_k$ is a positive-definite matrix.

**Question**: Does anyone know of any more literature on the scaled gradient descent algorithm, particularly its convergence? I cannot seem to find much online -- perhaps I am using an incorrect keyword?

Comment: Look up variable metric methods.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks, I'll take a look. Just curious, any idea why it is named that way?

Comment: I think of it this way: In absence of Hessian information, we can approximate $f$ at $x$ by $h \mapsto f(x)+ \langle g , h \rangle + {1 \over 2} \|h\|^2$ ($g$ is the gradient) and we minimise this approximation to get a search direction $h = -g$. If we have some (symmetric and positive definite) guess of the Hessian, say $D$, we can use the approximate $f$ at $x$ by $h \mapsto f(x)+ \langle g , h \rangle + {1 \over 2}  \langle h , D h \rangle$, which will give the search direction $h =- D^{-1} g$.

Comment: The map $h \mapsto  {1 \over 2}  \langle h , D h \rangle$ is a norm (metric) and we change the metric every so often, hence the term variable metric.